.NET MAUI Application class MainPage is Obsolete
I just migrated a small project to .NET 9 and it seems Application classes MainPage is now obselete, cannot find a direct solution for this
My current code:
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MainPage = new AppShell();
}

Also how would I access the MainPage now Globally like i used to with the Application.Current.MainPage
Any documentation links are appreciated as well
I tried Google but did not find anything relevant quickly

That's easy, first to set the MainPage now you need to create a new Window something like this
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState? activationState)
    {
        return new Window(new AppShell());
    }
}


Now to access this MainPage globally I would do something like:
var MainPage = Application.Current.Windows.FirstOrDefault()?.Page;

More information here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/whats-new/dotnet-9?view=net-maui-9.0
